# Jquery on hover start sliding images

Tags: jquery, image, hover, mouseover

this is what i got

```
<div class='slides'>

    <img src='image1.jpg' />
    <img src='image2.jpg' />
    <img src='image3.jpg' />
    <img src='image4.jpg' />
    <img src='image5.jpg' />

</div>
```

just random images inside div, positioned : absolute; so all are in the same position

What i need to do is, When somebody hovers on 'slides' div, it starts to slide images, inside it, on unhover sliding stops, and so on if i got more than 'slides' div, tried with jquery Cycle the following code

```
$('.slides').hover(
        function() {
                $(this).cycle({
                        fx:     'fade',
                    speed:   400,
                    timeout: 300,
                    pause:   0
                });
        },
        function(){
                $(this).cycle('stop');
        }
);
```

but it does not do the job, hope i find a solution, all help appreciated, thanks

Comment: problems happen when i use more than 'slides' div with jquery cycle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".slides").cycle({
                    fx:     'fade',
                    speed:   400,
                    timeout: 400,
                    pause:   0
                })
            .cycle('pause')
            .hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).cycle('resume');
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).cycle('pause');
                }
             );
```

It initiates the plugin and then immediately pauses it, then the hover will play and pause it respectively. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/HSE62/

Comment: no sorry, it paused the slider and played it all when i hovered, consider that i have more than div with class='slides'